# How do I put a label inside a Feynman diagram circle?

Tags: labels, feynmf, feynman

I have this simple Feynman diagram with a circle:

[image]

I would like to put the number "1" in the middle of that circle.

I've tried these:

- `\fmfiv{lab=1}{c}`
- `\fmfiv{lab=1}{.5[nw,se])`
- `\fmfiv{lab=1}{(.4999w, .5h)}`
- `\fmfiv{lab=1}{(.5001w, .5h)}`

but whatever constants I put, latex refuses to put it INSIDE the circle.

The latex:

```
\documentclass[24pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,epsf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

    \begin{fmffile}{2ptcorrection1}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(220,12)
    \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i1}
    \fmfright{o1}
    \fmf{plain}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes, left=1, tension=0.3}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{plain, right=1, tension=0.3}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{plain}{v2,o1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

btw, the coordinates are: "c" for center, sw, se, ne, nw.

Update: thank you hftf for the [answer](https://www.writelatex.com/805794hsgvmf#/1779325/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to make the label appear to be in the center of the circle by using a `phantom` (invisible) edge across the circle and setting the `label.dist` to `0` to place the label in the middle of that edge.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

    \begin{fmffile}{2ptcorrection1}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(220,12)
    \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i1}
    \fmfright{o1}
    \fmf{plain}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes, left=1, tension=0.3}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{plain, right=1, tension=0.3}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{plain}{v2,o1}

    % This is where the magic happens:
    \fmf{phantom,label.dist=0,label=1}{v1,v2}

    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: label positioned in the middle of a Feynman diagram circle]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done also with the new [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) package (see also the [project page](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman)).

Inside the `feynman` environment, first you draw the actual diagram within the `\diagram` macro, then you can use the usual Ti*k*Z commands to put labels (the syntax used there requires the `calc` library, which is loaded b default by Ti*k*Z-Feynman).  You have to compile with `lualatex` in order to take advantage of the automatic positioning of the vertices.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \diagram[layered layout, horizontal=a to d] {
      a --  b,
      b -- [scalar, half left] c -- [half left] b,
      c -- d,
    };
    \node [red] at ($(b)!0.5!(c)$) {1};
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]