# Circle with a cross inside feynmp

Tags: graphics, diagrams, feynmf

The below code produces essentially what I want but there must be a more elegant way and more automatized way. I want a circle with a cross inside it at a vertex:

```
\fmfv{d.sh=circle,d.f=empty,d.si=.1w,l=$\times$,label.dist=0}{v3}% v3 is the name of the vertex
```

But notice that if the circle becomes big, the cross will remain small. I want a circle with a cross inside it that has the same diameter as the circle no matter how big the circle is.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101761/qed-vertex-factor-rule or the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a [complete MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for the community to work with? Something like `\otimes` might be what you want, but without knowing the surrounding code I am unable to test.

Comment: I tried \otimes, looked nice. Can one enlarge \otimes?

Comment: With the `graphicx` package, `\scalebox{scalefactor}{code}` will enlarge, if scale>1.  If the code is math, `$` delimiters will be needed around `code`.

Comment: That worked like a charm Steven! One solution to this problem is: \fmfv{l=\scalebox{2}{$\otimes$},label.dist=0}{v3} So a combination of what you said and what @Paul Gessler suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I have never used Metafont before, and I also have only ever [touched feynmf once](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163535/how-do-i-put-a-label-inside-a-feynman-diagram-circle/163540#163540). Please comment if I did any of this completely wrong.

---

Since you never even provided a complete MWE, I had to just make this stuff up.

1. I used the `\fmfcmd` macro to define a `path`, which I named `otimes`, to draw a `⊗` shape.
   It is made by rotating four copies of a `⌔` quadrant. (Thanks to egreg for the [help](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15372872#15372872).)
2. I turned on `\fmfwizard` according to [footnote on page 17 of the feynmf manual](http://www.pd.infn.it/TeX/doc/latex/feynmf/manual.pdf#page=17):

   > If the variable `feynmfwizard` is `true` (e.g. after calling the `\fmfwizard` macro), it is also possible to specify [`shape` as] any METAFONT expression that evaluates to a `path`.
3. I set the vertex shape to `otimes` and the fill to `empty`. (Surprisingly, using another value for fill does not seem to break anything.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{foo}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(80,80)

\fmfcmd{
    % Please let me know if there’s a more efficient way to do this
    path quadrant, q[], otimes;
    quadrant = (0, 0) -- (0.5, 0) & quartercircle & (0, 0.5) -- (0, 0);
    for i=1 upto 4: q[i] = quadrant rotated (45 + 90*i); endfor
    otimes = q[1] & q[2] & q[3] & q[4] -- cycle;
}
\fmfwizard

\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{r}

\fmf{fermion}{i1,c,i2}
\fmf{photon}{c,r}
\fmfdot{c}
\fmfv{d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty}{r}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Notice how this scales “correctly” according to your requirements:

```
\fmfleft{a}
\fmfright{d}

\fmf{plain}{a,b,c,d}
\fmfv{d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty,d.si=.1w}{a}
\fmfv{d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty,d.si=.2w}{b}
\fmfv{d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty,d.si=.5w}{d}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice diagram,...