# How to use feynmf (feynmp)?

Tags: feynmf, feynmp

I would like to draw a tadpole diagram with a cross in a circle as the picture in the parenthesis but the double line is not necessary. [image]

I write the codes as below:

```
\begin{fmffile}{tadpole}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(50,25)
\fmfright{o1}
\fmfpoly{cross,pull=?}{v1}
\fmf{plain}{v1,o1}
\fmfdot{v1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

What I worry about is `\fmfpoly{cross,pull=?}{v1}`. I think this should be wrong, but I really don't know how to present a cross in a circle.

I hope somebody can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: `\otimes`? (in math mode)

Comment: @HenriMenke I am afraid this would not work since I need the external line to be connected with the \otimes symbol. And actually I hope to draw a dot at the point of junction.

Comment: Possibe duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175659/82917)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[\delta J(\otimes\mkern-7mu\cdot\!\!\mbox{---}) =0\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Edited to insert a dot at the junction.