# Tensor symbol as vertex in feynmp

Tags: metapost, feynmp, feynmp-auto

Consider the following example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0.05cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{.09cm}
\begin{fmffile}{simple_labels}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
  \fmfleft{i}
  \fmfright{o}
  \fmf{gluon}{i,v1,o}
  \end{fmfgraph*}%
  \end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

I would like to draw a tensor product symbol `\otimes` on the vertex `v1`, while making sure that it behaves "properly" regardless of how many lines enter the vertex (with "properly" I mean here that the lines attach at the right positions of the `\otimes`-symbol). I checked the [documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) and I think there is no such option.

Basically, I would like to have a command in the spirit of `\fmfblob{<size>}{<vertex>}` to do this... Is there an easy way to achieve this?

**Edit:** @campa pointed me to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175659/circle-with-a-cross-inside-feynmp), which defines a new command to draw the `\otimes`-symbol. This seems like a good start, but it just slaps the `\otimes` symbol over the line without adjusting the points where the two lines meet the `\otimes`-symbol...

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0.05cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\fmfotimes#1#2{%
  \fmfbuf@={d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty,d.ang=45,d.si=#1}%
  \fmfcmd{vvertex ("\the\fmfbuf@", \fmfpfx{#2});}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{.09cm}
\begin{fmffile}{simple_labels}
  \fmfframe(2,12.5)(2,-12.5){%
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
    \fmfcmd{
    path otimes;
    otimes :=
    for i = 0 upto 4: 1/2dir 45i .. endfor
    1/2left --
    for i=right,up,left,down:
        1/2i -- origin --
    endfor
    for i = 4 upto 8: 1/2dir 45i .. endfor
    cycle;
    }
    \fmfwizard
  \fmfleft{i}
  \fmfright{o}
  \fmf{gluon}{i,v1,o}
    \fmfotimes{.15w}{v1} %Try with another size
  \end{fmfgraph*}%
  }
  \fmfframe(2,12.5)(2,-12.5){%
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
      \fmfleft{i}
      \fmfrightn{o}{2}
      \fmf{gluon}{i,v1}
      \fmf{gluon}{o1,v1}
      \fmf{gluon}{o2,v1}
      \fmfotimes{0.15w}{v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}%
  }
  \fmfframe(2,12.5)(2,-12.5){%
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
      \fmfleftn{i}{2}
      \fmfrightn{o}{2}
      \fmf{gluon}{i1,v1}
      \fmf{gluon}{o1,v1}
      \fmf{gluon}{o2,v1}
      \fmf{gluon}{i2,v1}
      \fmfotimes{0.15w}{v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}%
  }
  \end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circle with a cross inside feynmp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175659/circle-with-a-cross-inside-feynmp)

Comment: @campa I'd say it's a good start, but no. It just slaps the `\otimes` symbol over the line without adjusting the points where the lines meet...

Comment: Excuse me. But is it possible, please, to see an output to understand your request? What is your output and what you expected?

Comment: @Sebastiano make any diagram you want including the command `\fmfblob{.15w}{v1}` and replace the blob in the diagram with an `\otimes` symbol. I'm currently on the go, but I'll draw something up later and post it here..

Comment: @Sito If I not see the drawing also done with your fingers...I not understand. Excuse me.